# Django - User pre_save seems called after validation

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I need to generate a username if none is given when creating or updating a user.

I though about using a `pre_save` signal

```python
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='autocreate_username')
def create_username(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.username == None:
        instance.username = generate_random_username()
```

But the user seems to be inserted before the signal call.

```python
>>> user = User(email='machin@chouette.com')
>>> user.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):  
...  
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

Default `username` was set to empty string and not `None` so I did

```python
if not instance.username:
```

in my signal callback

Comment: How about `if not instance.username:`?